# Show brands on Magento product pages

Tags: php, html, magento, attributes

I have an attribute named `manufacturer` which contains my products brands. Like: `Apple Co`
and my brands images are stored in: `media/wysiwyg/queldorei/shopper/brands`. With names like: `apple_co`
Now I want to show my brands images in the product pages. and I want theme to be clickable and head me to a page with all of those brands products.

I putted bottom code in: `template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct();
 $manufacturerName = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
 $manufacturerId = $_product->getManufacturer();
 echo '<a href="/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]='.$manufacturerId.'">' ?>
 <img src="../media/wysiwyg/queldorei/shopper/brands/<?php echo str_replace(' ', '_',$manufacturerName); ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $manufacturerName; ?>" /></a>
```

it shows the brand in product page but when i click on it, i face to this error :

```
The requested URL /catalogsearch/advanced/result/ was not found on this server.
```

Comment: Please provide all the code that is required to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With an attribute of brands rather than manufacturer, should work.

```
 <?php if($_product->getBrand()): 
         $brandName = $_product->getAttributeText('brand');                      
         $brandImg  = strtolower(str_replace("&","",$_product->getAttributeText('brand'))); 
         $brandImg  = str_replace(" ","-",$brandImg);
         $brandImg  = str_replace("--","-",$brandImg); 
     ?>

 <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB) . 'brands/?brand=' . urlencode($brandName) ?>">
 <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'image/route/'  . $brandImg . '.jpg' ?>" alt="View more" title="View more">
 </a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i changed brand to manufacture but  again when i click on brand image this error comes up: `The requested URL /manufacturers/ was not found on this server.`